# ASP.NET Web Service - Passing a base object with list/collection?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

We need to create a simple web service in ASP.NET that can be called from PHP or other languages.  This in turn will be used to update records in a database for an item submission.

The core part is fairly simple, we have a base set of fields for the object - first name, last name, birth date, city, etc.
In addition however we need to accept a list of items associated with that object that can range from 0-n.
Jan 1 2009, ABC
May 1 2010, 123
Jun 30 2010, XXXXX

What would be the best way to structure this so it can be easily passed to the ASP.NET web service and processed as a single call for the entire object?  Would passing the list of items as a single delimted string be a wise approach?
Ex: Jan 1 2009, ABC|May 1 2010, 123|Jun 30 2010, XXXXX

Comment: Will you be using asmx web services or WCF?

Answer (score 0):

If you define a structure like:

```
class WebObject
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   string[] Parameters { get;set; }
}
```

You can specify in your method to just accept a WebObject. Will go fine with 99% of the PHP libraries, as well as JavaScript libraries etc.

F.e. this will just work against the function `void Process(WebObject obj)`:

```
someJavascriptPiece.Process({ Name: "Jan", Parameters: ['param1', 'param2'] });
```